# Specify pane percentage in tmuxinator project

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

How can I specify a pane percentage in tmuxinator ?

Eg:

```
 project_name: ad_dev
 project_root: ~/Programming/WWW/Rails/projects/ApparelDreamDev
 rvm: ruby-1.9.2-p290@apparel_dev
 pre: SQL
 tabs:
   - editor:
       layout: main-vertical
       panes:
         - vim 75%  
         - #empty, will just run plain bash
         - top
```

eg: the vim pane would take 75% of the screen... is there a way to specify this ? or where in the documentation should I look ? Can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: If it is okay to change it for all layouts and tmuxinator configs, there is a tmux option `main-pane-width` which supports percentages.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The layout should be specified in the `layout:` line. But you are not limited to the five preset layouts (such as main-vertical). From the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html):

```
In addition, select-layout may be used to apply a previously used layout - 
the list-windows command displays the layout of each window in a form 
suitable for use with select-layout.  For example:

       $ tmux list-windows
       0: ksh [159x48]
           layout: bb62,159x48,0,0{79x48,0,0,79x48,80,0}
       $ tmux select-layout bb62,159x48,0,0{79x48,0,0,79x48,80,0}

 tmux automatically adjusts the size of the layout for the current window
 size.  Note that a layout cannot be applied to a window with more panes
 than that from which the layout was originally defined.
```

First set up your layout just how you like it - you can adjust widths with `resize-pane` until it is just right for you. Then run `tmux list-windows`. And then you should be able to use the `layout:` line from the output unaltered in tmuxinator.conf

So based on the output from your gist:

```
0: tmux [208x73] [layout b147,208x73,0,0[208x62,0,0,208x10,0,63{104x10,0,63,103x10,105,63}]] (active)
```

The relevant section of the tmuxinator conf file should be:

```
  - editor:
       layout: b147,208x73,0,0[208x62,0,0,208x10,0,63{104x10,0,63,103x10,105,63}]
       panes:
         - vim
         - #empty, will just run plain bash
         - top
```

Comment: tmux list-windows gave me the following output ( https://gist.github.com/2324001 ). How would the tmuxinator layout line look according to that output ?

Comment: I didn't understand how to run the command `tmux list-windows` at first. Then I realized it was obvious. 1) Outside of your tmux session (detach or open a new console window) run the command like any other shell command. 2) Enter command mode (`PREFIX :`) within tmux and use the command `list-windows`

Comment: I think it should be made clear in the answer that the same number of panes listed by the ```list-panes``` command should be specified under the ```panes:``` section. For example, if 6 panes are defined 6 lines should appear under ```panes:```, even if they only contain a ```-``` (saying do nothing in this pane). If not the window will not be formatted correctly as described by ```list-panes``` output.

Comment: Some may find this command useful in scripts to just print the layout portion: `tmux list-windows | sed -n 's/.*layout \(.*\)] @.*/\1/p'`

Comment: I think nowadays (tmux 3.2) you need to have parentheses around the layout.