# List windows output truncated

Tags: tmux

Issuing the command on a windows with a vertical split display the following result:

```
0: root  (1 panes) [170x41] [layout b03d,170x41,0,0,0] @0
1: normal  (2 panes) [170x41] [layout fbd8,170x41,0,0{84x41,0,0,1,85x41,85,0,4}] @1
2: TSS- (6 panes) [170x41] [layout f690,170x41,0,0[170x14,0,0{84x14,0,0,2,85x14,85,2
7: bundle* (2 panes) [170x41] [layout 4973,170x41,0,0{85x41,0,0,43,84x41,86,0,44}] )
```

Note that the third line is truncated. If one tries to move the cursor to the right the last characters turns on '$',

```
2: TSS- (6 panes) [170x41] [layout f690,170x41,0,0[170x14,0,0{84x14,0,0,2,85x14,85,$
```

, indicating that this is end of the line.

Issuing the command after closing the second pane:

```
0: root  (1 panes) [170x41] [layout b03d,170x41,0,0,0] @0
1: normal  (2 panes) [170x41] [layout fbd8,170x41,0,0{84x41,0,0,1,85x41,85,0,4}] @1
2: TSS- (6 panes) [170x41] [layout f690,170x41,0,0[170x14,0,0{84x14,0,0,2,85x14,85,0,11},170x13,0,15{84x13,0,15,5,85x13,85,15,12},170x12,0,29{84x12,0,29,6,85x12,85,29,132
7: bundle* (1 panes) [170x41] [layout d853,170x41,0,0,43] @7 (active)
```

The output of the third line is still truncated. I've read the man page but couldn't figure out how to read the full contents of that line.

I intend to use it to set a custom layout, as explained on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976282/717124)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a bug on tmux, which is being addressed [on this ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tickets/125/).

Comment: The ticket seems to have expired. Please update the link.