# How to split two vertical pane inside a horizontal pane in tmux using tmuxinator

Tags: linux, vim, tmux, tmuxinator

Currently am having this in my tmuxinator yml file,

```
windows:
   - editor:
       layout: main-horizontal 
       panes:
         - vim
         - 

  - server: rails s
```

This gives me 2 windows one for editor and another for server. In editor window i have two panes one for vim and another one is a blank pane where i can use some commands. But i want to split that blank pane further into two vertical pane i.e,

```
windows:
   - editor:
       layout: main-horizontal 
       panes:
         - vim
         - (I want to split this pane into two vertical pane, in which i can run my rails console in one pane and i can use the other for executing commands)

  - server: rails s
```

So totally i will have 3 panes in my first window. Could any one please help me in this.

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution without using window dimensions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify pane percentage in tmuxinator project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812000/specify-pane-percentage-in-tmuxinator-project)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If neither `main-horizontal` nor `main-vertical` is working for you. Then you can adjust your current layout the way you want to be and use the tmux cmd: `list-windows` witch will return the current layout. In Example:

`list-windows` returns:

`1: bash [190x41] [layout c9f8,190x41,0,0[190x20,0,0,190x20,0,21{95x20,0,21,94x20
,96,21}]]`

Then the yaml will be:

```
windows:
   - editor:
       layout: c9f8,190x41,0,0[190x20,0,0,190x20,0,21{95x20,0,21,94x20,96,21}]
       panes:
         - vim
         - foo1
         - foo2
  - server: rails s
```

Answer (score 0):

The `main-vertical` layout arranges the panes as described.

[image: main-vertical layout]

```yaml
windows:
  - editor:
      layout: main-vertical
      panes:
        - vim
        -
        - bin/rails c
```

If the main pane is too small, you can configure that globally in tmux using `main-pane-width`.