# horizontal pane inside vertical pane with tmuxinator

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I want to setup a new window with tmuxinator with the panes like this:

```
#########
# 1 #   #
##### 3 #
# 2 #   #
#########
```

i.e., two `main-vertical` panes with the first one having an `horizontal` one inside of it, something along the lines of:

```
windows:
  - editor:
      layout: main-vertical
      panes:
        - gst
        - layout: horizontal
          - gulp
          - python script.py
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this without using window dimensions as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560963/how-to-split-two-vertical-pane-inside-a-horizontal-pane-in-tmux-using-tmuxinator) ? Or some alternative to tmuxinator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to use [tmxup](https://github.com/tony/tmuxp) instead, here's the solution:

```yaml
session_name: statuspage
windows:
- window_name: main dev
  layout: main-vertical
  shell_command_before:
    - workon statuspage
  panes:
    - shell_command:
        - python statuspage.py
    - gst
    - pwd
```

Comment: Your answer does not actually answer the question.

Comment: From your "answer" I still don't know if its possible to do it in tmuxinator or not.  So no; it's not a good answer.

Comment: I can see that you recently added "Or some alternative.." to the end of the question to make your answer more applicable... at least that's a start.

Comment: @Mario the point of my question was to find a way how to do it, not necessarily with tmuxinator. So I obviously edited it to make it more clear ;)

Comment: Fair enough, but without specifying that alternative software is acceptable your answer was invalid.  I would just like to point out that a big part of Stack Overflow is good answers rising to the top so that many developers are helped, not just the person asking.  This is why "I just did something else" is not valid, because people who actually want the answer to the question being asked are not being helped.  I am not trying to be mean, but it's important to the longevity of Stack Overflow that we use our votes to hold each other to a high standard of quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close to that pretty easily with

```
windows:
   - cli:
       layout: main-vertical
       panes:
         - one:
           - gst
         - two:
           - gulp
         - three:
           - python script.py
```

produces

```
#########
#   # 2 #
# 1 ##### 
#   # 3 #
#########
```